# How to configure outlook to send me Tracking report for my emails - Office 2011 for mac

Tags: office-365

I want to configure my outlook 2011 for Mac to send me a tracking report for my sent emails.

Note: My Email Hosted by: Office 365.

Any idea?

Comment: read receipt and or delivered receipt

Comment: Prefer Both reports.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some instructions on how you can do that. You may also consider using a plugin called sidekick by hubspot. It's a chrome extension that allows you to track emails (not through a program) but I use it with gmail. I don't think it requires permission from the person, which makes it a little less conspicuous.

Let me know if this helps.

[image: Email Tracking through Outlook]